# Waze crashes on start

Tags: apps

I have Waze installed on my Windows Phone, and it worked well - until today. Now every time I open Waze it quits right away. I didn't install anything on the phone that caused this...

I've tried:

- Restarting the phone - same
- Uninstall and re-install Waze - same (even before entering my account)

**Details**

- Nokia Lumia 920
- Windows phone 8.1 Update, OS version: 8.10.14219.341
- Firmware version: 3051.50009.1451.1004
- Hardware version: 6.5.0.4
- Waze version 3.7.4.5

[Cross-post in Waze forum](https://www.waze.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=164310)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was resolved today, and other people confirm on the linked Waze thread. Probably a server side issue.

Comment: Please mark you answer so that your question will be marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem with Lumia 930 and waze. Was updated last week and now it is working.
Only the linking with Facebook is still broken.